# How to define PrivateRoute in React.js which works only after authentication?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router

I have a backend API to which I send email and password. In return, it provides an auth token after successful authentication. I have written the code for sending this API request in a file **auth.js**. It looks like this:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const auth = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  login(user) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email: user.email, password: user.password });
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/userauth/login", body, config)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
        this.isAuthenticated = true;

        return res.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
```

I am calling `auth` in **App.js**. Inside this I file I have a private route '/dashboard' which can be accessed only after authentication. If not authenticated, it redirects to '/login' route.

Here is the code for it:

```
import { auth } from "./actions/auth";
// rest of imports ...

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    </Router>
  );
}
// ... ...
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

Also, this `onSubmit` function of my login form looks like this:

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };

    auth.login(user).then(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.props.history.push("/dashboard");
      }
    });
  }
```

Now whenever I input the correct `email` and `password` in login form, I successfully redirect to `/dashboard` route. But if I reload `/dashboard` route even after login, It again sends me back to login page. 
From my understanding, it should stay on the dashboard page as `isAuthenticated` is set to true after login.

Thus my private route should have worked. Then what am I missing? Also for the record, I am following [this](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/) tutorial for creating PrivateRoute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reload the page, react state is lost.

You already saved the token when login is succcessfull. So we can take advantage of that token to recover authentication state.

As long as you have a token and the token is not expired yet, the user can stay authenticated.

To check token expiration, we can use [jwt-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) package.

You can modify your auth.js like this to accomplish this:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export const auth = {
  isAuthenticated: isValidToken(),
  login(user) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    };
    const body = JSON.stringify({ email: user.email, password: user.password });
    return axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/userauth/login", body, config)
      .then(res => {
        localStorage.setItem("token", res.data.token);
        this.isAuthenticated = true; //we may remove this line if it works without it

        return res.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        this.isAuthenticated = false;
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};

const isValidToken = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  if (token && isValid(token)) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};

const isValid = token => {
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);

  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000;

  if (currentTime > decoded.exp) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, is there a problem with my PrivateRoute as well? I have a strong feeling it is wrong.

Comment: @TarunKhare if you followed that tutorial correctly, I see no reason that private route doesn't work.  Can you apply my answer to your app and give feedback please?

Answer (score 1):

React state resets after refresh.
Your problem is your `auth state` is resetting after refresh.

You should make sure you `re-authenticate` yourself everytime when page refreshes, ideally you should do it in routes component in `useEffect()` or `componentDidMount()` depending on whether you are using hooks or class.

As @Steve pointed out, you can just grab the token from `localStorage`.

Comment: I don't think they need to re-authenticate in the backend.  They already set the auth token to localStorage.  They just need to grab that when the component mounts.

Comment: Yes, I completely missed that part. I will edit my answer. Thanks @SteveK